# Why does String.Format converts minus to parenthesis

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am using `String.Format` to add `$` sign into values.

```
 var result = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(amount));
```

when `amount` is negative it converts minus sign into parenthesis- like below

```
-11.00 --> ($11.00)
```

I need this

```
-11.00 --> -$11.00
```

**How can I fix this ?**

Comment: See CurrencyNegativePattern [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString). And it doesn't add "a $" but the current currency symbol

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses *is* the preferred accounting format to display negative currency, in the US at least. See [this UX.SE post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/preferred-format-to-display-negative-currency-us-english/37703).

If you don't want to follow that convention, you can create your own `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
var format = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").NumberFormat;

// "1" means "-$n"
format.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;

string.Format(format, "{0:C}", -1m) // "-$1.00"
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=net-6.0) for a list of the values that you can put in `CurrencyNegativePattern`.

Answer (score 4):

You actually have a lot of control over how your numbers are output, if you don't want to use the standard cultures. In fact you can make up you're own currency symbols if you want.

Here's how you can customize the `decimal.ToString` output:

```
var money = -4.21345m;

var ni = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo()
{
    CurrencySymbol = "₿",
    CurrencyDecimalDigits = 5,
};

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    ni.CurrencyNegativePattern = i;
    Console.WriteLine(money.ToString("C", ni));
}
```

That gives me:

```
(₿4.21345)
-₿4.21345
₿-4.21345
₿4.21345-
(4.21345₿)
-4.21345₿
4.21345-₿
4.21345₿-
-4.21345 ₿
-₿ 4.21345
4.21345 ₿-
₿ 4.21345-
₿ -4.21345
4.21345- ₿
(₿ 4.21345)
(4.21345 ₿)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but for the C literal the output ($11.00) is correct. It is a typical bookkeeping format for writing negative numbers. You could change this in your Windows settings, but then the change would be global for the system and probably that's not what you want.

The easy solution would be to use:

```
var result = string.Format("${0:0.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(amount));
```

But then the USD sign is hard-coded (by the way that is the more "correct" variant than writing the USD sign after the minus as shown in your last code line). If you want to make it flexible and nevertheless custom, you could get the currency information and the decimal separator from the system culture settings until its fitting your requirements.